# Plot Legend and Asymptote and to enlarge region

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to plot some functions where one of them is and a vertical asymptote
but it cannot put into the Legend (the asymptote is 1 ). Also, another problem is when trying to improve the axis size and font. It does not show the asymptote which value is 1.

```
Fig1 = LogPlot[{ t^2/4, (8 t^3)/27, (81 t^4)/256 }, {t, 0, 1}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotLegends -> {"q=1/2 ", "q=2/3", "q=3/4"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Tau]", "Log r"}, 
  Epilog -> InfiniteLine[{{1, -2}, {1, 2}}], 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Directive[Dashing[0.002], Black], 
    Directive[Dashing[0.00], Black], 
    Directive[Dashing[0.03], Black] }, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, LabelStyle -> Directive[33], 
  FrameStyle -> Thick]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
plotstyles = {Black, Directive[Dashing[0.002], Black], Directive[Dashing[0.03], Black]};

LogPlot[{t^2/4, (8 t^3)/27, (81 t^4)/256}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Append[plotstyles, Dotted],
  {"q=1/2 ", "q=2/3", "q=3/4", "vertical line"}], 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
 FrameLabel -> {"τ", "Log r"}, 
 Epilog -> {Dotted, InfiniteLine[{{1, -2}, {1, 2}}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> plotstyles, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[.05]}, {0, 0}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

where I used

1. `PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[.05]}, {0, 0}}` to extend the domain so that the vertical line is visible.
2. `LineLegend[...]` to specify the styles and labels for all the lines including the vertical line.

Comment: @irondonio, does this answer your question?